# Get the current phones number with contact framework api ios

Tags: swift, contacts-framework

Is it possible to get the current phone's number from contacts permission in Swift?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift, I want to get phone number(not udid) and email from device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34690415/swift-i-want-to-get-phone-numbernot-udid-and-email-from-device)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible anymore

> "For security reasons, iPhone OS restricts an application (including
>   its preferences and data) to a unique location in the file system.
>   This restriction is part of the security feature known as the
>   application's "sandbox." The sandbox is a set of fine-grained controls
>   limiting an application's access to files, preferences, network
>   resources, hardware, and so on."
>
> The device's phone number is not available within your application's
>   container. You will need to revise your application to read only
>   within your directory container and resubmit your binary to iTunes
>   Connect in order for your application to be reconsidered for the App
>   Store

Comment: Instead of quoting an answer from the question I linked to, you should instead vote to close this question as a duplicate.